# Django/Python resize image

Tags: python, django, image-manipulation

I have a image from

```
files = request.FILES['new_photo'].read()
```

and i want to know it's size and possibly resize it.
How i can do it?

thanks.

UPD

before. i read() file and gave this string and some info? to SQL function. And she save it on ftp.

how i can get data same as the data returned from read() method?

i try to use Image.tostring()

and save it. But i have 0x0px image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a small snippet from one of my web applications (sightly modified), which creates a thumbnail with the maximum size of 200x200 pixels. Maybe you can use some parts of it:

```
from PIL import Image

image = request.FILES['new_photo']
if image:
    img = Image.open(image)
    img.save(path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
        secure_filename('upload-%d.jpg' % self.obj.id)), 'JPEG')
    img.thumbnail((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
        secure_filename('upload-%d.200.jpg' % self.obj.id)), 'JPEG')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use PIL for processing images .
http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Comment: Yes. But how? i don't don't know image size.  and function like fromString() have size argument

Comment: use StringIO:
img = Image.open(StringIO(files))
after which:
img.size contains the size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

User one of the thumbnail libraries available such as http://djangothumbnails.com/ or more http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ThumbNails

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add "automated image processing" to your project, you might consider using [**Django-imagekit**](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit).

The author has included Installion and usage instructions on this [**Github Repo page**](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit).

Hope this helps you as I found it from the same search as I found this Question :)